# How to create this specfic design using grid

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a layout like [on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju49H.png), i have tried with this grid and I couldn't achieve.

```
<ul class = "container">
     <li class = "first"> </li>
     <li class = "second"> </li>
     <li class = "third"> </li>
     <li class = "fourth"> </li>
</ul>
```

```
.container{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   gap: 20px;
}

.first{
   grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both html and css is changed, for layout it is not recommended to use `ul` and `li`.
You need to span through the grid based on your requirement.

```css
.container{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   gap: 20px;
   width: 500px;
   background:#ccc;
   height:500px;
}

.first{
  background:red;
   grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
.second{
  background:green;
   grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.third{
  background:yellow;
   grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
.fourth{
  background:orange;
   grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
     <div class = "first"> </div>
     <div class = "second"> </div>
     <div class = "third"> </div>
     <div class = "fourth"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i try this and its work

In HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second"></div>
      <div class="third"></div>
      <div class="fourth"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

In CSS

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.first {
  border: 5px solid black;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.second {
  border: 5px solid black;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.third {
  border: 5px solid black;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.fourth {
  border: 5px solid black;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```